# C++ Declaring multi-dimensional array in header

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, header

I want to declare a static multidimensional array in my class.

I have done the following:

header (myclass.h):

```
static int my_array[][][];
```

source file (myclass.cpp):

```
MyClass::my_array[3][4][5];
```

I have the problem of multidimensional array who must have bounds for all dimensions except the first...

Therefore I have tried to write this in the header file:

```
static int my_array[3][4][5];
```

And then nothing in the .cpp file.

But this time I got this error in the static functions that use my array: "undefined reference to MyClass::my_array"...

What is the way to solve it?

Comment: See the last part in http://stackoverflow.com/a/12574407/673730. i.e. define the `static` member in the cpp: `int MyClass::my_array[3][4][5];`

Comment: So i don't write anything in the header file? Is there any way to fix that? I find it easier for me when all the attributes are defined in the header file...

Comment: You do both. Did you read the linked answer?